# Firebase pagination - EndBefore doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

'm trying to implement pagination in my React app using Firebase. I want to load the next/previous set of documents based on the last/first document in the current set.

The pagination towards the next set is working fine, but I'm facing an issue with the pagination towards the previous set. Whenever I try to load the previous set, it always loads the first set of documents.

Here's my code:

```
import { FirebaseDB } from 'contexts/FirebaseContext';
import { collection, getDocs, limit, orderBy, query, startAfter, where, getCountFromServer, endBefore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const pageSize = 9;

export const getDataUsers = async (user, startAfterDoc = null, endBeforeDoc = null) => {
    const data = [];
    const constraints = [collection(FirebaseDB, 'usuarios'), orderBy('efectividad', 'desc')];
    const totalUsers = await getCountFromServer(...constraints);
    if (startAfterDoc) {
        constraints.push(startAfter(startAfterDoc));
    }
    if (endBeforeDoc) {
        constraints.push(endBefore(endBeforeDoc));
    }
    constraints.push(limit(pageSize));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(...constraints));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const newData = { ...doc.data() };
        delete newData.password;
        delete newData.URL_INE;
        delete newData.URL_REVERSO;
        data.push(newData);
    });
    return {
        data,
        totalUsers: totalUsers.data().count,
        firstDoc: querySnapshot.docs[0],
        lastUser: querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1]
    };
};
```

In the code above, I am using the endBefore method to get the previous set of documents. I pass the last document in the current set (endBeforeDoc) to the endBefore method, but it doesn't work as expected it always returns the first documents.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks for reading me

I attach my other code

```
const fetchDataUsers = async (startAfterDoc = null, endBeforeDoc = null) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            const { data, totalUsers, firstDoc, lastUser } = await getDataUsers(user, startAfterDoc, endBeforeDoc);
            setDataUsers(data);
            lastU.current = lastUser;
            firstU.current = firstDoc;
            setIsLoading(false);
            return { totalUsers };
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            setIsLoading(false);
            setOpenModalError(true);
            return [];
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const firstRender = async () => {
            const { totalUsers } = await fetchDataUsers();
            totalPages.current = Math.floor(totalUsers / 9);
        };
        firstRender();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    const loadMore = async () => {
        await fetchDataUsers(lastU.current, null);
        setPage(page + 1);
    };

    const loadPrevious = async () => {
        await fetchDataUsers(null, firstU.current);
        setPage(page - 1);
    };
```

I have already put console.log before this line

constraints.push(endBefore(endBeforeDoc));

to know that the correct document is really arriving and if it is arriving instead of using the endBefore method use endAt

I hope you can take a look at my code code tell me more oh less what could be happening I appreciate it, thank you very much

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: same problem here. anyone knows how to fix this?